# Get frames from Picamera and add opencv filters in realtime

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, picamera

According to [this](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html?highlight=opencv#capturing-to-an-opencv-object) Picamera document, Picamera can capturing frame as openCV object. but seems not working .
how can i get frames from Picamera  and add opencv filters in realtime.
Rpi 3b+ .
Python 2.7
i need an example code please.

```
import time
import picamera
import numpy as np
import cv2

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (320, 240)
    camera.framerate = 24
    time.sleep(2)
    image = np.empty((240 * 320 * 3,), dtype=np.uint8)
    camera.capture(image, 'bgr')
    image = image.reshape((240, 320, 3))
```

Comment: Are you using Bullseye version? I used picamera2.

Comment: No i used Raspbian.

Comment: What is your Raspberry pi model?

Comment: Raspberry pi 3B+

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 23rd April, 2022. Ok. I'm going back to your previously original coded. I'm using picamera v1. kindly, try to understanding. `while cap.isOpened()` is equivalent to `camera.start_preview()` You need time interval how long do you want to stay. So I set time.sleep(30) for 30 seconds. Do not used `image.reshape`. You already have  `camera.resolution = (320, 240)`. So here is previously coded. So I commented it out. try this:

```
import time
import picamera
import numpy as np
import cv2

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (320, 240)
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.framerate = 24
    time.sleep(30)
    #image = np.empty((240 * 320 * 3,), dtype=np.uint8)
    camera.capture(image, 'bgr')
    #image = image.reshape((240, 320, 3))
```

Here another one how to save multiple images.

```
import time
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(2)
    for filename in camera.capture_continuous('img{counter:03d}.jpg'):
        print('Captured %s' % filename)
        time.sleep(10) # wait 10 seconds
```

Comment: Tnx.Can you write an example code

Comment: See my answer.  I test your previously code and start_preview add timer too. here is [link] https://projects-raspberry.com/getting-started-with-raspberry-pi-camera/  And this too [link] https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/

Comment: If you needed to work with OpenCV using picamera. Help is here. Do not hesitate to ask.